# The installer information on the recovery server is damaged - Sierra

Tags: macos

I have a MacBook Air 2017 | 13.3" (Intel CPU). I erased the data from "Disk Utility" and now I'm trying to reinstall the OS.

From macOS Utilities, once I click "Reinstall macOS" for reinstalling Sierra (the OS that was pre-installed once I bought the MacBook) I receive this error message: "The installer information on the recovery server is damaged".

[Here](https://ibb.co/pXBBqrP) a screenshot of the logs

Comment: You could try to create a USB installer/ Do you have access to another Mac? If so, what model/year and version of macOS?

Comment: @DavidAnderson No, I don't have access to another Mac.